# How detect that all JavaScripts completed in GeckoWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#

I use GeckoWebBrowser component for get some webpages. But I don't know when page JavaScripts fully completed.

For detecting page full load I use event DocumentCompleted.

```
private GeckoWebBrowser wb = new GeckoWebBrowser();
private bool doc_loaded = false;

wb.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;
doc_loaded = false;
wb.Navigate(url);
Wait_Load();

 private void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doc_loaded = true;
        }

 private void Wait_Load()
        {
            while (doc_loaded == false)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Application.RaiseIdle(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
```

How detect that all JavaScripts completed in GeckoWebBrowser?

Comment: Do you control the contents of the page, or it's an arbitrary one?

Comment: It can be any web page with JavaScripts, arbitrary one